# Edit table function only works unpredictably

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

what im trying to do:
change table data if value is like the passed criteria

code:

```vb
Sub editTableData(tableName As String, rw As Integer, col As Integer, str As String)
    Sheet1.ListObjects(tableName).Range(rw, col).value = str
End Sub
Sub EDITTABLEDATAONOTHERPAGE()
    Call editTableData("statement", 20, 6, "Why did this work?")
End Sub
```

result:

```
03/19/2020, WAL-MART SUPERCENTER, 67.07, blank, blank, "Why did this work?"
```

[image]

but when called here:

```vb
Function categorize(criteria As String) As Double
    Dim statement As listobject, statementNames As Range, statementCategory As Range, statementCredit As Range, name As Range
    Set statement = Sheet1.ListObjects("statement")
    Set statementNames = Sheet1.ListObjects("statement").ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange
    Set statementCategory = Sheet1.ListObjects("statement").ListColumns("Category").DataBodyRange
    Set statementCredit = Sheet1.ListObjects("statement").ListColumns("Credit").DataBodyRange
    '---this is the part that matters:--------------------------------
    For Each name In statementNames
        If name.value Like criteria + "*" Then
            Call editTableData(statement.name, name.row, statementCategory.column, statement.name)
            categorize = categorize + statementCredit(name.row, statementCredit.column).value
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

it gets to the method, it passes editTableData("statement", 20, 6, "statement") as String, int, int, String respectively (so the same data) but it just stops working and i dont know why.

anything enlightening would be nice, here is the table that i am using this table to call the formula as well:

a picture of the table

[image]

---

Update/amendment:
Here is the debug photos:
[CALLING THE METHOD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ofIz.png)
in the method (reference locals window for values):
[in the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSQpN.png)

and when I press F8 Again this time, it crashed... 
No error message, none of the other cells above or below were changed so its just not working at all. if it were an index problem that would be easy enough to fix

Comment: No error messages?

Comment: Is the loop not executing? Set a breakpoint and step thru it in order to debug it.

Comment: You are indexing into a range derived from `DataBodyRange` (which starts on row 2 if your headers are in row 1) using the cell's `Row` property - your indexing will be one row off at least.

Comment: @braX you'll see in the photo that the loop is executing

Comment: @TimWilliams no there is no error messages, and no cell data is changed, it just exits the loop and does nothing

Comment: In the line `Call editTableData(statement.name, name.row, statementCategory.column, statement.name)` there is `statemant.name` twice. Doesn't seem right. Can you share the sub calling the function? I don't like `name` as a `For Each Control Variable`. And a `+` before `"*"`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 You're right, the logic here isn't complete, eventually it will say the table that it is in (ie food, entertainment etc.) however im just passing a string for a proof of concept.

I thought you were on to something with name being the loop variable and ".Name" as an object variable being an issue. so i changed the variable name to n and same issue persisted. 

the +"*" is just the regex to allow me to choose all things that start with (in this case) WAL-MART